# How to recreate XNA's SkinnedModelProcessor

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I have a model that is rigged and skinned and I would like to be able to move the bones programmatically (as opposed to a preset animation stored int he fbx file)

I can load the model fine, and see that the bones have been loaded, but changing the bone transforms doesnt seem to affect the rendered model.

I am looking at the sample project here:

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model

It looks like it uses an extended ModelProcessor (aka SkinnedModelProcessor) to over the DefaultEffect and return a MaterialProcessorDefaultEffect.SkinnedEffect.  I am guessing that somewhere along the lines this makes the renderer transform the mesh vertices using the model bones (with a vertex shader???)

I am having problems getting this SkinnedModelProcessor working in my own project. The sample uses the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline assembly. In my project I dont see the item in the regular list of .net references. So I added it manually from the filesystem.

The problem there is that as soon as I compile, visual studio says that it cant find that namespace, even though right up until I compile it shows everything working fine

How can I recreate the SkinnedModelProcessor from the sample in my own project

or

How can I get changes to bones reflect in my rendered model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the reason getting the reference to the pipeline assembly was such a problem is that you have to segregate that code into a separate special project using the XNA Content Pipeline Extension Library project template

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and I'm in the works on creating my own simple Skinned Model Manipulator.  For the time being the easiest way is to just create a new method in the AnimationPlayer class that will allow you to alter the boneTransforms.

I made something like this for your help:

```
    public void SetPose(Matrix rootTransform, Matrix[] boneAlteration)
    {
        skinningDataValue.BindPose.CopyTo(boneTransforms, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < boneTransforms.Length; i++)
        {
            boneTransforms[i] = boneAlteration[i] * boneTransforms[i];
        }
        UpdateWorldTransforms(rootTransform);
        UpdateSkinTransforms();
    }
```

For this method the Matrix Array boneAlteration is simply an array of Identity Matrices for  maintaining the original bindPose.  Change any of the matrices before passing it into this method to rotate the bone for that corresponding index.